# Declaring variables in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm learning Perl, and facing some inconsistency between running a program from the command line versus interactively executing it interactively in the debugger.

Specifically, I invoke the Perl debugger with `perl -d -e 1`, and run this code line-by-line

```
my $a = 1;
print $a;

$b = 2;
print $b;
```

In the output I am only seeing the value of `$b`, while `$a` seems to be undefined. At the same time, when I execute the same statements with `perl myscript.pl`, both values are shown in the output. Why does this happen? What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest using [reply](https://metacpan.org/pod/reply) instead of the built-in Perl debugger. It's simply a whole lot nicer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The debugger is a wholly different environment from run time Perl. Each line you enter behaves like a separate block, and if you declare a *lexical* variable like `my $a` then it will be deleted immediately after the command.

It is as if you had written

```
{ my $a = 1; }
{ print $a; }

{ $b = 2; }
{ print $b; }
```

Ordinarily you will declare lexical variables at an appropriate point in the program so that they don't disappear before you need them. But if you want to use the debugger to play with the language then you need to use only *package* variables, which never disappear and are what you get by default if you don't use `my`.

Command line "one-liner" Perl programs usually do the same thing, but it's a lesson you will have to unlearn when you come to writing proper Perl programs. You will be using `use strict` and `use warnings` at the head of every program, and `strict` requires that you *choose* between lexical or package variables by using `my` or `our` respectively. If you try to use a variable that you haven't previously declared then your program won't compile.

Also *never* use `$a` or `$b` in your code. Apart from being dreadful variable names, they are reserved for use by the `sort` operator.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can often work around this in the debugger by putting all your code on one line: for example, if I type `my $a = 42; print $a` at the  debugger prompt, it prints `42`.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now. Is there another way of doing it, rather than putting it all in one line?

Comment: @ojy: I've extended my answer. If you want your variables to retain their value in the debugger then just don't use `my`. But *never* do that in a program

Comment: @ojy: If you have some Perl code in a file, you can run it from the debugger with `do 'filename'`